# Trying to pose model but the pose snaps back to original immediately

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, bones, inverse-kinematics

I'm having a frustrating time moving my IK arms. I've tried unchecking "Connected" on bone group but then it warps the movement. This movement shown here is what I want but I somehow seem unable to get it to stay. I was able to get the arm to move up, but now it just snaps back to that even though I have a new frame. Thank you so much! File here: https://pasteall.org/blend/3819e248f5e84c9786281ef84aadd9ba
[image]

Comment: hello could you please share the armature only? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: in the process of uploading i think i figured it out! my problem was protected layers... i don't really understand, but i will look more into it. and wow, a blender specific file share site, love it!! thank you so much :) https://pasteall.org/blend/3819e248f5e84c9786281ef84aadd9ba

Comment: Actually, my question is, what is the blue line that shows when I move the hand? When I added everything else back into the scene, I am unable to move it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bone called *4arm.L* has an *IK* constraint with *handIK.L* as target, which means *handIK.L* is its controller and *4arm.L* is going to stick to *handIK.L* as soon as you are in *Pose* mode:

[image]

The bone called *handIK.L* is not visible for the moment because its layer is not activated, if you activate it you'll see it:

[image]